# ImageMap - zoom in when hovering over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I'm currently working on the following:

I have a big map of the world. On it, I have clickable areas, defined by image maps. What you can click on, are the countries, and those have a link that lead to a page about the country.

```
  <img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100-img" src="worldmap.png" alt="" usemap="#image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" width="6460" height="3455" border="0" class="map" />
    <map id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" name="image-maps-2017-08-25-161100"></map>
```

An example for an area:

```
<area style="outline: none;" title="Portugal" alt="Portugal"
                              coords="2909.33349609375,1327.3333740234375,2913.33349609375,1324.3333740234375,2919.33349609375,1321.3333740234375,2921.33349609375,1329.3333740234375,2927.33349609375,1328.3333740234375,2936.33349609375,1328.3333740234375,2940.33349609375,1326.3333740234375,2949.33349609375,1331.3333740234375,2948.33349609375,1339.3333740234375,2945.33349609375,1343.3333740234375,2944.33349609375,1349.3333740234375,2945.33349609375,1358.3333740234375,2941.33349609375,1363.3333740234375,2939.33349609375,1371.3333740234375,2935.33349609375,1372.3333740234375,2932.33349609375,1373.3333740234375,2936.33349609375,1382.3333740234375,2938.33349609375,1392.3333740234375,2935.33349609375,1397.3333740234375,2940.33349609375,1406.3333740234375,2936.33349609375,1410.3333740234375,2933.33349609375,1416.3333740234375,2934.33349609375,1425.3333740234375,2922.33349609375,1427.3333740234375,2910.33349609375,1427.3333740234375,2912.33349609375,1417.3333740234375,2912.33349609375,1407.3333740234375,2914.33349609375,1398.3333740234375,2909.33349609375,1397.3333740234375,2907.33349609375,1398.3333740234375,2911.33349609375,1393.3333740234375,2910.33349609375,1390.3333740234375,2908.33349609375,1388.3333740234375,2903.33349609375,1392.3333740234375,2901.33349609375,1392.3333740234375,2903.33349609375,1380.3333740234375,2908.33349609375,1377.3333740234375,2911.33349609375,1366.3333740234375,2913.33349609375,1355.3333740234375,2914.33349609375,1346.3333740234375,2913.33349609375,1337.3333740234375"
                              shape="poly" href="portugal.html" target="_self"/>
```

What I'm now trying to achieve is a very cool feature (in my opinion), if it works:

When you hover over one area of the image map, the map should zoom in on this point (or even better: show exactly the part within the area in big). So the image is more then 6000px in width, but only displayed (on my monitor) in about 1000px.

So how cool would it be to have the map and when hovering over portugal, portugal is getting bigger (so like zoomed in), and when you hover out again, the normal map is there.

[image: normal map]

[image: When hovering over Portugal]

So this is an example of what I mean, first there is the normal map, and when hovering over portugal, it get's big.

Ofcourse, it shouldn't be that blurred (this is just because I did it in 2 minutes in paint) and as I said, the optimal thing would be to have exactly the borders of the area zoomed in.

I hope you got what I mean.

I tried around a bit with the css `transform` property, but first, I don't know when to change it, and second, I have no idea how to choose that specific part of the map.

Using Javascript/jQuery would be no problem, if needed.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle with your existing code

Comment: @Thusitha the fiddle would only show the code I provided above... Not sure, if the `transform` is what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't suppose you figured this out? I'm working on something similar, map of a state with each county imagemapped out, I'd like to zoom on hover with transform but I've no idea what that'll do to the coordinates I have mapped out.